# Extra parameter in .trigger() does not reach the listener function: what is happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am tinkering with this code:

```
var items;

function getMessage(index) {
    if (index == items.size()) return;
    var item = items.eq(index);
    $.get('/message/' + index,
        function(response) {
            item.html(response);
            $("ul").trigger('updated', index);
        }
    );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    items = $(".message");

    $("ul").bind('updated',
        function(event, i) {
            getMessage(i + 1);
        }
    );
    getMessage(0);

});
```

And this html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="message"></li>
    <li class="message"></li>
    <li class="message"></li>
</ul>
```

According to the documentation of the jQuery `.trigger()` function,

> "A single [extra] parameter can be passed without using an array."

But in the above code, the function listening on the "update" event never gets the parameter "index" (passed in line 9), unless I enclose it in brackets like this:

```
$("ul").trigger('updated', [index]);
```

I am not even sure if this is something related specifically to jQuery. Could you help me understand what is happening?

Comment: it works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/gSFd4/ What browser are you using?

Comment: ...but it won't if we start from 0 like I did: http://jsfiddle.net/gSFd4/2/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 Nash

Doesn't looks like if jQuery isn't handling the case of one parameter passed without an Array. Verified both from the API & the latest source.

The only exception i m guessing is that the value is received by a variable called data. And it goes like this:

```
data ? jQuery.makeArray( data ) : [];
```

Now in JavaScript, if the data variable has value 0 (number), the if check returns false. So, when the first time you would run it, it will not execute makeArray().

Again, this is only a think-aloud guess. Please don't get misguided, if that is not the case.

Comment: You are right! I now realize that the problem only happens when passing 0, any other number will actually work. I'm going to report this as a bug to the jQuery folks. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, it was fixed in this commit https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/c17f589ec99e8309e813a4081eed47f39a0c6120

Comment: @nash Thanks for pointing it out, it appears thr is 1.6.2 on the cards very soon.